# How to resolve this error in joomla 1.5Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script

Tags: joomla1.5

I completed the entire website in joomla 1.5 version and hosted my website also but once I login form my home page im getting this error form online server in localhost its working fine can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

I have used some plugins like joomfish, jQuery login register module so is there any problem with my plugin or with my server? Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

This is the error

> Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I think you should update Joomla. The 1.5 is a very old version and uses obsolete PHP and MySQL functions. I suggest you to back up the website data and upgrade joomla to 2.* . Joomla! 1.5 has also got some SQL injection problems. Hope to be useful, bye.

Comment: thank u so much  i will upgrade joomla but can u pls tell me what is reason for this error bezs i cont figure it out

Comment: Maybe because of the caps? ($_GET[] instead of $_get[]